How to Configure log4net in Unity to Capture Context-Specific Logs from Debug.Log
I’m working on a custom LoggerService in Unity that needs to write logs to a file (using a Rolling Appender), send logs to an HTTP endpoint, and print logs to Unity’s console. I want this system to be transparent for other developers so that they can continue using the standard Unity logging methods, like Debug.Log, Debug.LogError, and Debug.LogWarning.
To achieve this, I’m using log4net for logging, where I have created different appenders for file, HTTP, and Unity’s console. I’ve also set up Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded to capture Unity log messages and route them to log4net like so:
private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerService");

public void Initialize()
{
    InitializeLog4Net();
    Application.logMessageReceivedThreaded += OnLogMessageReceived;
}

private void OnLogMessageReceived(string condition, string stacktrace, LogType type)
{
    switch (type)
    {
        case LogType.Error:
            log.Error(condition + "\n" + ShortStackTrace(stacktrace));
            break;
        case LogType.Assert:
        case LogType.Exception:
            log.Fatal(condition + "\n" + ShortStackTrace(stacktrace));
            break;
        case LogType.Warning:
            log.Warn(condition);
            break;
        case LogType.Log:
            log.Info(condition);
            break;
        default:
            log.Debug(condition);
            break;
    }
}

The issue I’m facing is that all the log messages are coming from the same context, i.e., LogManager.GetLogger("LoggerService"). I want to be able to dynamically set the logger context based on where the log is coming from (e.g., the class or method), so I can get more detailed, context-specific logs.
Can anyone suggest a solution or approach for achieving this?
Thanks in advance!

Don't you have that information in the stack trace though?
